# Ensure that request is not sent

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

How to ensure in tests that request is not sent? Imagine we have form, we send request only when all fields are done. First test - to check whether filled form sends request - is easy, just waiting until calls number is bigger than before.

What about the second - to check whether partially filled form doesn't send request. I can't do simple `expect(current calls === prev calls)` - they are already equal. Should I wait for a second and see whether the numbers are still equal, is there a better solution?

```
mock = new MockAdapter(axios);

(...)

test('GIVEN filled form WHEN click save data THEN request is sent', async () => {
    // GIVEN
    await renderPage();
    const prevCallsLength = { ...mock }.history.put.length;

    // WHEN
    await fillWholeForm();

    userEvent.click(screen.getByText(/Save/));
    const currCalls = mock.history.put;

    // THEN
    await waitFor(() => expect(currCalls).toHaveLength(prevCallsLength + 1));
  });

test('GIVEN partially filled form WHEN click save data THEN request is not sent', async () => {
    // GIVEN
    await renderPage();
    const prevCallsLength = { ...mock }.history.put.length;

    // WHEN
    await fillPartiallyForm();

    userEvent.click(screen.getByText(/Save/));
    const currCalls = mock.history.put;

    // THEN
    ???

  });
```